# HashiCorp Vault with Spring boot 3, getting error Cannot create authentication mechanism for TOKEN when using APPROLE

Tags: spring-boot, vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I have a Spring boot 3 service and when I try to run it I got an error

```
 Cannot create authentication mechanism for TOKEN. This method requires either a Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) or a token file
```

I'm trying to use APPROLE and I keep getting this error

The yaml I have is

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      fail-fast: true
    vault:
      uri: https://vault.secret-management.some-url
      fail-fast: true
      authentication: APPROLE
      app-role:
        role-id: ${env.ROLE_ID}
        secret-id: ${env.SECRET_ID}
```

The dependencies I have in my project are

- spring boot 3.0.4
- spring-cloud-starter-vault-config 4.0.0

Any idea how to solve this problem?

I have tried to run the service

```bash
mvn spring-boot:run -pl application -D"spring-boot.run.profiles=local"
```

And I got the referred error

Comment: Debugging I see the properties are not getting used.  VaultProperties are the default ones, not the ones I want

Comment: Putting the vault properties in a bootstrap.yml file solved the problem